# Create Paginator using Angular

Tags: angular

how i can build a paginator for my basic table model? using angular material, bootstrap or other.

currently im using angular material and bootstrap in modal

component.html

```
<section  style="margin-left: 2%" class="row mt-5">
  <table class="table table-hover">       
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">Data</th>
          <th scope="col">Data</th>

        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let data of data">
         <td>{{Data.data}}</td> 
         <td>{{Data.data}}</td> 

        <td>
       <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button" href="#updatedata" data-toggle="modal"  (click)="dataClicked(data)">Edit</button>
       <button class="btn btn-danger" mwlConfirmationPopover [popoverTitle]="popoverTitle"[popoverMessage]="popoverMessage"
        placement="left" (confirm)="delete(data)"(cancel)="cancelClicked = true" > Delete  </button>
        </td>    
        </tr>
            <div  *ngIf="data?.length === 0"  layout-align="center">
                <h3> No Data for Show </h3>
            </div>  
      </tbody>
    </table>
    </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a paginator that I built with angular: https://github.com/HADDADSOHAIB/EC/tree/master/FE/src/app/shared/Component/paginator

Comment: Feel free to ask any question if you don't understand something